# Online virus scanning service with remote file submission?

Tags: malware, virus

I have some links that contain hacking tool and whatnot and I want to pass them to a virus scanning service. The thing is that I don't want to download them to my pc and upload them to their service, but rather to have it scan the files remotely by just passing them the URLs. Do you know of any service with a simple way/api to do that (I'm using PHP). Virustotal.com has something like that but their PHP classes/scripts are missing from their site! Thanks.

Comment: You can find the VirusTotal libraries mirrored on some sites: https://www.google.com/search?q=PHP_VirusTotal_API_Functions.zip

Comment: Wepawet might be useful, too, but it's more limited and not a replacement for something like Virustotal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried [NoVirusThanks.org](https://www.NoVirusThanks.org/) and it worked fine. There isn't an "API", but you can alter the generic submission link so you pass the parameter (ie remote file link) you want to be scanned, essentially manipulating the GET method of the program (nothing malicious though).

Answer (score 4):

There are services like [ScanThis!](http://scanthis.net/) and [URLVoid](http://vscan.urlvoid.com) which are similar to VirusTotal. None seem to have an API that you are looking for.  However, more interesting is how effective these systems actually are.  Passing the EICAR test virus pattern to ScanThis! for example, comes back with a "not infected" report.  URLVoid, however, does indicate the file is infected.

In addition to finding an API, you will also want to ensure that the service you select has an appropriate scanning engine.  If you have samples of infected files, then it might behoove you test them to ensure that they are effective.  Otherwise you're no better off.